# Are there differences in memory structure between JVM8 and JVM11?

Tags: memory, garbage-collection, jvm

I have a fast question - are there any differences in memory structure between JVM 8 and JVM 11?

For example, in JVM 8 permanent generation was replaced with metaspace. I'm asking about changes like this. Unfortunately, I can't find any articles on the internet about that.

Comment: I don't think there are any.  Googling for articles on something that hasn't happened is unlikely to give you useful results :-)  Read https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html#NewFeature for info on what >>has<< changed.

Comment: I think the main difference is that the G1 collector is the default collector from Java 9 onward.

Comment: I'm not aware of any changes comparable to the permgen/metaspace change in Java 8. I'd say it's mostly about garbage collectors - new ones like ZGC, Shenadoah (and epsilon) as well as important improvements in G1 GC (parallel full gc in Java 10 and ability to return memory to the operating system without needing to do full gc in Java 12).
Some info here: https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2019/03/changes-to-garbage-collection-in-java-12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through the list of [Java Enhancement Proposals (JEPs)](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/0), the following ones seem to be relevant to *memory structure* in some way:

- [JEP 143: Improve Contended Locking](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/143)
- [JEP 197: Segmented Code Cache](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/197)
- [JEP 248: Make G1 the Default Garbage Collector](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/248)
- [JEP 254: Compact Strings](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254)
- [JEP 270: Reserved Stack Areas for Critical Sections](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/270)
- [JEP 310: Application Class-Data Sharing](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/310)
- [JEP 316: Heap Allocation on Alternative Memory Devices](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/316)
- [JEP 333: ZGC: A Scalable Low-Latency Garbage Collector (Experimental)](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/333)

G1-by-default (JEP 248) may need some adjustments to tuning and monitoring, similar to the PermGen removal, and so does the segmented code cache (JEP 197).